# Why is the "pmvnorm" result different when the input matrix are covariance and correlation matrix?

Tags: r

The result is different when using a variance matrix and a correlation matrix. Why is this happening?

I will write down the results directly for convenience.

**Variance matrix - naming as co**
0.1234   0.125
0.1250   0.245

**Correlation matrix - naming as coo (made by cov2cor function)**
1.0000  0.7189
0.7189  1.0000

**Result**
pmvnorm(mean=c(1,1),sigma=co, lower=rep(-Inf,2), upper=c(0.7,4)
**0.1965493**

pmvnorm(mean=c(1,1),corr=coo, lower=rep(-Inf,2), upper=c(0.7,4)
**0.3820885**

I made a covariance matrix, and we got a correlation matrix using covariance matrix. And these two values were implemented, and the result was different.

It is code.

> install.packages("mvtnorm")
>   library(mvtnorm)
>   co <- matrix(c(0.1234,0.125,0.125,0.245),2,2)
>   coo <- cov2cor(co)
>   pmvnorm(mean=c(1,1),sigma=co, lower=rep(-Inf,2), upper=c(0.7,4)
>   pmvnorm(mean=c(1,1),corr=coo, lower=rep(-Inf,2), upper=c(0.7,4)

Please let me know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per `?pmvnorm` (emphasis mine)

> sigma: the covariance matrix of dimension n. Either ‘corr’ or
>             ‘sigma’ can be specified. **If ‘sigma’ is given, the problem is
>             standardized.** If neither ‘corr’ nor ‘sigma’ is given, the
>             identity matrix is used for ‘sigma’.

So to make both calculations consistent you need to give *standardised upper limits* when giving a correlation matrix.

```
# Using covariance matrix sigma
cov <- matrix(c(0.1234,0.125,0.125,0.245), 2, 2);
x1 <- pmvnorm(mean = c(1, 1), sigma = cov, lower = -Inf, upper = c(0.7, 4));
x1;
#[1] 0.1965493
#attr(,"error")
#[1] 1e-15
#attr(,"msg")
#[1] "Normal Completion"

# Using correlation matrix corr
# Note: Need to scale the upper limits
cor <- cov2cor(cov);
x2 <- pmvnorm(mean = c(0, 0), corr = cor, lower = -Inf, upper = (c(0.7, 4) - c(1, 1)) / sqrt(diag(cov)));
x2;
#[1] 0.1965493
#attr(,"error")
#[1] 1e-15
#attr(,"msg")
#[1] "Normal Completion"
```

---

PS. It's a bit hidden, but `?pmvnorm` includes a simpler example on the complementarity of both approaches.

```
 # Correlation and Covariance

 a <- pmvnorm(lower=-Inf, upper=c(2,2), sigma = diag(2)*2)
 b <- pmvnorm(lower=-Inf, upper=c(2,2)/sqrt(2), corr=diag(2))
 stopifnot(all.equal(round(a,5) , round(b, 5)))
```

Comment: No worries. Glad to help @Skkst